# Without pro-knowledge of HTML/CSS, what can I use to create a web 2.0-like website for free?

Tags: html, css, web-applications

Without pro-knowledge of HTML/CSS, what can I use to create a web 2.0-like website for free?
I don't know how to create professional looking icons, smooth effects, borders, shadows, etc.

Are there WYSIWIG editors out there, web services, or other resources I can use to put something together in relatively little time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Squarespace](http://www.squarespace.com/) is the one I most hear mentioned by web professionals.  If you go to their site you can see that they're big on the web 2.0 aesthetic.  It's probably the service I'd recommend as well.

Otherwise [Weebly](http://www.weebly.com/) is also popular and I'm sure a Google search could bring up plenty more.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out Webnode (http://www.webnode.com). There are a few out there but this is the one that I used.